# Password storage in code. How to make it safe?

Tags: c#, security

I have made an application in C# that sends mail and SMS ( SMS via an API). It works perfectly, but my concern is that someone will decompile my application, which has the credentials to both the sending emailaccount and the API. The API works with

```
private void sendSMS(String username, String password, String destination, String body, String sender)
{
    String browserURL = "http://api.messagebird.com/api/sms?username=" 
        + username + "&password=" + password + "&destination=" 
        + destination + "&body=" + body + "&sender=" + sender;
    _w.Navigate(browserURL);
}
```

Just by decompiling or using wireshark the "hacker" can send SMS as he desires, while the application is designed to send him an SMS on special events like a security breach in his house. also I don't want the hacker be able to change the E-mail's password, so other users don't get their email anymore. 
How can I prevent this? 
The code is designed to run on the customers own computer/server and alert him for example if there was motion detection.

I thank you all for you answers. I choose to let the customer fill in their own credentials for mail and SMS services, just to avoid having a security breach.

Comment: Have you considered obfuscating your source code? There are several options and products that can do that for you...

Comment: I have considered it, but if you have enough ICT knowledge you can just use ctr+f to search for an "@" and find the credentials, even in the most "messy code". Or am I understanding obfuscating wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not put secrets in code. Put them in an encrypted, safe place, on disk and read it when needed.

Obfuscation is exactly what it says: it hides rather than it protects.

Also: do not send credentials unencrypted over the internet.

Comment: Adding to this, an encrypted configuration file and using https might help.

Comment: Anything that's encrypted can of course be decrypted therefore encryption isn't necessarily the safest option. The safest option would be to not store it at all on the client (however, sometimes that isn't always possible). The safety of the password is ultimately bound by the safety of the machine itself.

Comment: @James - of course. If someone gained access to the computer running the code nearly all protection is useless. In the end it all depends on who or what you trust (the user, the disk, the PC, the network, the  receiver (often forgotten))

Comment: Authentication works either with difficult/non-replicable unique tokens, or with secrets, or a combination of both. As Erno suggested, put your authentication information (authentication hash = the secret) on an external drive, for example a USB stick (= unique physical token). Use a USB stick supporting hardware encryption if security demands are somewhat higher. If security demands are even higher than that, you should not hang out in SO but rather consult an (somewhat expensive) security expert.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to protect your password is simply to not store it all, at least locally.

As soon as you store *anything* client-side the safety of the data is only as strong as the safety of the hardware it's sitting on. For example, if someone were to install your app on a public machine (e.g. internet cafe) anyone who knows what they are doing has the potential to get access to your password. It's less of a problem if you can be sure that the app is only going to be installed on private machines and only used by "good" users (which, ultimately, you can't).

How secure you need this password to be is really down to you. The questions you really need to ask yourself are

- What sort of damage could be done if they *did* manage to get the password?
- What measures do I have in place to detect any sort of misuse? (e.g. IP logging etc.)
- What procedures do I have in place if someone was misusing the API? (e.g. password change)

The 3rd point poses a few problems when storing the password locally. If you detected misuse of the API and consequently changed the password, how can you cascade those changes down to the clients?

For me, the safest way to avoid all these issues is to have your app query your API server and have it return some sort of authentication token (aka API token). This token would then be passed along with any request back to your (hopefully, secure) server which validates the token and, if authorised, forwards the SMS request onto the SMS server.

Comment: Note that you still need to authenticate the client before the server passes back a token.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd yep and there are safe ways of doing that. For example, re-directing the user to a secure single sign-on webpage which then re-directs back to the app with the authorised token (similar to what you see with the OAuth protocol).

Comment: Once you're querying a server for an authentication token, you may as well be querying a server for permission to post, and pass the **user's** username & password, keeping that used to send the SMS on the server as the SMS is sent from there.

Comment: @JonHanna that's effectively what I was referring to because essentially you would need *some* sort of credentials to authorize usage of the service. The user would need prompted somehow for their credentials though so whether that be via a web-page or even a dialog in the app (as to avoid physically storing it) and of course all this would all happen, preferably, over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData`

> This class provides access to the Data Protection API (DPAPI)
>   available in Microsoft Windows 2000 and later operating systems. This
>   is a service that is provided by the operating system and does not
>   require additional libraries. It provides protection using the user or
>   machine credentials to encrypt or decrypt data.
>
> The class consists of two wrappers for the unmanaged DPAPI, Protect
>   and Unprotect. These two methods can be used to encrypt and decrypt
>   data such as passwords, keys, and connection strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx

Comment: I'm affraid that if the source is decompiled you still can read the password. As in your example `byte [] secret = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };` is still just a plain string before encrypting it.

Comment: It's probably better not to send the credentials to the client at all but make the client send a request to your server and your server will be calling SMS gateway. That's way you've solved your problem by not having it in the first place.

Comment: You would still have to authenticate the client when it sends a request.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd that can be easily achieved with PKI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure

Comment: @JakubKonecki - Just for the sake of the argument: do you trust the guy, medium, process that delivers your private key? Security is never easy.

Comment: @JakubKonecki that means you need a certificate installed client-side...which again means it's open to theft. If someone stole the cert they could masquerade themselves as you.